# Print all destinations from selected State in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a Distination form where the user have 2 opitons.

> 1 - Select Country
>
> 2 - Select State

The problem is that the the destinations don't correspond to the selected country and state. For example: I choose Pulau Ujong for country and the option "Any" from the states.After clicking "Find A Venue" button it shows all the destinations.

That's  the sidebar structure:

```
<div class="sidebar leftpart">
                        <h1>Destinations</h1>
                        <form action="<?php echo home_url('destination-results'); ?>" method="GET">
                        <div class="fieldarea">
                            <label>Country</label>
                            <select id="venue_finder_country_select" name="country_id">
                            <?php if ( ! class_exists( 'SM_Venue_Destination_Tools' ) ): ?>
                                <option>United States</option><option>Mexico</option><option>Canada</option><option>Caribbean</option>
                            <?php
                                else:
                                    $countries = SM_Venue_Destination_Tools::get_destination_countries();
                                    if ( ! empty( $countries ) ) {
                                        foreach( $countries as $country ) {
                                            if ( ! empty( $selected_contry ) && $selected_contry == $country['ID'] ) {
                                                $selected = 'selected';
                                            } else {
                                                $selected = '';
                                            }
                                            echo '<option value="'. $country['ID'] .'"'. $selected .'>'. $country['post_title'] .'</option>';
                                        }
                                    }
                            endif;
                            ?>
                            </select>
                            <label>State</label>
                            <select id="veneue_finder_state_select" name="state_id">
    
                            <?php if ( ! class_exists( 'SM_Venue_Destination_Tools' ) ): ?>
                                <option>Alaska</option><option>Delaware</option><option>California</option><option>Arkansas</option>
                            <?php else:
                                if ( ! empty( $selected_contry ) ) {
                                    $country_id = $selected_contry;
                                } else {
                                    $country_id = SM_Venue_Destination_Tools::get_destination_country_id_by_name('United States');
                                }
                                $states = array();
    
                                if ( ! empty( $country_id ) ) {
                                  $states = SM_Venue_Destination_Tools::get_destination_states( $country_id );
                                }
    
                                echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
                                if ( ! empty( $states ) ) {
                                    foreach( $states as $state ) {
                                        if ( ! empty( $selected_state ) && $selected_state == $state['ID'] ) {
                                            $selected = 'selected';
                                        } else {
                                            $selected = '';
                                        }
                                        echo '<option value="'. $state['ID'] .'" '. $selected .'>'. $state['post_title'] .'</option>';
                                    }
                                }
                                endif;
                                ?>
                            </select>
    
                            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/?page_id=1195" target="_blank"><input name="" type="submit" value="Find A Venue"></a>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- end sidebar left part -->
```

And the queries:

```
Fetch all destination states by a country
     * 
     * @return array all states by a country, array with post_ID and post_title
     */
    public static function get_destination_states( $country_id ) { 
        global $wpdb;
        if(!empty($country_id)){
            // We need to make sure the destination state has ACF "state"
            $place_type_tax_id = '';
            $place_type_tax = get_term_by( 'slug', 'state', 'place-type' );
            if ( ! empty( $place_type_tax ) && ! is_wp_error( $place_type_tax ) ) {
                $place_type_tax_id = $place_type_tax->term_id;
            }
            
            //$states = $wpdb->get_results( "select ID, post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $country_id order by post_title asc", ARRAY_A );
            $states = $wpdb->get_results( "select p.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta pm inner join $wpdb->posts p where p.post_parent = $country_id and p.ID = pm.post_id and meta_value = '$place_type_tax_id' order by post_title asc" , ARRAY_A );
            
            return $states;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get a list of all cities in a State
     */
    public static function get_cities_from_state( $state_id ) { 
        global $wpdb;
        if(!empty($state_id)){
            $cities = $wpdb->get_col( "select ID from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id order by post_title asc" );
            return $cities;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

Not sure how to create a new query which will get all the destinations corresponded to the selected country and state. And finally, where should i use the query ? Also, im not familiar with the wordpress database structure (1 of the main reasons i'm asking this question)

Comment: Could you give us the table structure and some sample data to work with ?

Comment: You mean the wp_postmeta table ?

Comment: Whichever table your countries, states and destinations are stored in.

Comment: Im trying to find'em. Give me a min